# VS2022: Dismissing column selection mode immediately like in VS2019?

Tags: selection, visual-studio-2022

### I want to go back to the behaviour of VS2019

- In VS2019, you can immediately escape from column selection mode by releasing ALT-SHIFT and then just pressing a cursor key.
- But in VS2022, i have to press ESC additionally. Otherwise it will somehow stay in column selection mode, which might be some sort of
  *"feature"*. I don't want this. This seems like a small thing, but when extensively
  using column selection mode, it can considerably reduce productivity compared to VS2019.

**Is there any way (setting, etc.) to turn the behavior back to like it is in VS2019?** (btw: VS2019 behaves the same elegant way as e. g. notepad++)

---

Remarks:

- (i am forced to use VS2022 for several reasons)
- (i found possible duplicates to this question, but they don't quite point out the
  problem)
- (i wasn't able to add a tag like "column-selection-mode")

Thanks.

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback to let them know what you want.

Comment: Note that you can press ESC *alone* to dismiss column-editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2022, Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced > Use box selection.

Enable the Use box selection checkbox to disable the new multi caret selection features and use the simpler 2019 style box selection instead.

Also, you can remap the "Edit.SelectionCancel" keyboard shortcut for the "Text Editor" to some key closer than ESC. I tried mapping this to the UpArrow key, but it overrides moving the caret up in normal mode, so thats not a solution. If they had a "Edit.ColumnSelectionCancel" property then that would work perfect.